# openAL get/set offset in seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, openal

I use OpenAL to play background music. At one point, I need to get the exact current position on the track. I tried using `alGetSourcef(_source, AL_SEC_OFFSET, &offset);` and it works perfectly on iOS 4, but on iOS 3 it returns an `int` (no decimal places). This is not accurate enough, as I need accuracy to at least 3 decimal places (I then use this offset info to jump to another point on the track, and a rounded down value means it ends up jumping to an inaccurate position).

Would it be possible to get the `AL_SAMPLE_OFFSET` or `AL_BYTE_OFFSET` and then convert that value to seconds?

Sound file: 16bit PCM WAV with sample rate of 22050.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a sample rate of 22050 samples per second, all you need to do is divide the sample offset by 22050 to get the time.

Comment: Thanks so much. Funny how I never actually realized the connection between sample and sample, I tried multiplying by powers of ten before and it obviously didn't work. Thanks!